# How to request authorization for Health Kit when needed?

Tags: ios, cocoa, healthkit

In my app I'm integrating Apple HealthKit support. I figured how to request authorization for the different types.

However, if user goes to Health app, and changes authorization for all those types back to NO, my app is not able to use any data. Calling requestAuthorizationToShareTypes again doesn't bring Health viewController with the options again.

I found the post on stackoverflow, where it was suggested to change the types, which will trick Health app to open its authorization view again. It actually works.

Is there any less tricky and more reasonable ways to do it?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Check if access is allowed using `authorizationStatusForType`, and, if not allowed, present an alert informing the user that permission is required and offering to take them to the settings page to fix it.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Comment: Thank you David, I thought of this. Is this the only option? Basically there is no way to send user to Health app authorization screen more than once?

Comment: Generally speaking, the philosophy of Apple's user permissions is that the user really shouldn't be harassed by repeated permission requests.  Even this approach really shouldn't be taken unless there's really no functionality without the missing permissions.